# Definition of the same class in the different TUs

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a program linking of two different TUs as follows:

main.cpp

```
int a = 6;

struct A
{
    int b = a;
};

int main(){ }
```

slave.cpp

```
static int a = 42;

struct A
{
    int b = a;
};
```

I expect that linker will throw an error in that case, beacuse (`N3797::3.2/6` [basic.def.odr]):

> There can be more than one definition of a class type [...]
>
> Given such an entity named D defined in more than one translation
>   unit, then
>
> [...]
>
> — in each definition of D, corresponding names,
>   looked up according to 3.4, shall refer to an entity defined within
>   the definition of D, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload
>   resolution (13.3) and after matching of partial template
>   specialization (14.8.3), except that a name can refer to a
>   non-volatile const object with internal or no linkage if the object
>   has the same literal type in all definitions of D, and the object is
>   initialized with a constant expression (5.19), and the object is not
>   odr-used, and the object has the same value in all definitions of D;
>
> [...]

So in my case `a` refers to the different entity in the different TUs, therefore it shouldn't be linked correctly. But in my case it does. I'm using `gcc -o bin main.o slave.o` with `gcc 4.7.2-2ubuntu1`. Is it a bug?

Comment: The standard does not say that violating that rule will lead to a linker error. What it says is "If the definitions of D do not satisfy
these requirements, then the behavior is undefined." Undefined behaviour may include linking without error messages.

Comment: (Meme) http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/safety-not-guaranteed